# checkbox value auto check using php syntax error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laratrust with roles and permission, now in my Roles edit-page, I loop all my permissions and I'm trying to make the checkbox auto check based on the permissions that are already given to a certain role.

Now I'm getting an error:

> (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting)

Could anyone fix my code?

Edit.Blade

```
<div class="from-group">
    @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input 
                    type="checkbox"  
                    name="permissions[]" 
                    value="{{$permission->id}}" 
                    @if($role->permissions) 
                        @if(in_array($permission->id, $role->permissions->pluck('id')))
                            checked 
                        @endif 
                    @endif
                 >
                 <span>
                     {{$permission->display_name}} 
                     <em>({{$permission->description}})</em>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your condition to

```
@if(in_array($permission->id, $role->permissions->pluck('id')->toArray() ))
```

you miss last `)` bracket
And The in_array() function searches an array for a specific value so second value must be an array

Comment: bro i'm getting error..in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Comment: Answer updated plz chk

Comment: What do i write after the in_array()?

Comment: Check the $role->permissions->pluck('id') return an array

Comment: still showing the error bro..

Comment: Paste the error here

Comment: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Comment: Try $role->permissions->pluck('id')-> toArray()

Comment: boom what a genius i love u bro whahahaha thank u so much i wanna buy u a beer sheeet.... i have been stack for this problem how many days thank u so much bro..